# Self join Criteria Queries

Tags: java, jpa, hibernate-criteria, self-join

I have the following select query and for this query in the second left join, I am making self-join with the same table with the same column.I want this same query to be in a criteria query.
I have converted the following query to the criteria query but I am getting the following error saying

> Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.SingularAttributeImpl@1b3142f] on this ManagedType [com.glenwood.glaceemr.server.application.models.ProblemHistory]

```
select * from problem_report 
left join  problem_history a on problem_report_uniqueid=a.problem_history_problem_uniqueid  
**left join problem_history b ON a.problem_history_problem_uniqueid = b.problem_history_problem_uniqueid**
```

In Spring Entity class I have made spring

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "problem_history")
public class ProblemHistory implements Serializable{
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, 
     generator="problem_history_id_seq")
     @SequenceGenerator(name ="problem_history_id_seq", 
     sequenceName="problem_history_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
     @Column(name="problem_history_id")
     private Integer problemHistoryId;
    enter code here

     @Column(name="problem_history_problem_uniqueid")
    private Integer problemHistoryProblemUniqueid;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonManagedReference

@JoinColumn(name="problem_history_problem_uniqueid",referencedColumnName="problem_history_problem_uniqueid",insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private ProblemHistory problemhistoryRef;
```

In the service Implementation

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<Object> cq = builder.createQuery();
            Root<ProblemReport> root = cq.from(ProblemReport.class);
            //Root<ProblemHistory> root1 = cq.from(ProblemHistory.class);

            Join<ProblemReport,ProblemDataCheck> pblmDataCheckJoin=root.join("pbldatacheck",JoinType.LEFT);
            Join<ProblemReport,ProblemHistory> pblmReportHistoryJoin=root.join(ProblemReport_.problemHistory,JoinType.LEFT);
            Join<ProblemHistory,ProblemHistory> pblmhstryJoin=pblmReportHistoryJoin.join("problemhistoryRef",JoinType.LEFT);
```

Let me know is there anyway to perform self join in above criteria query.

Comment: why are you sometimes trying to join using the static metamodel (`ProblemReport_.problemHistory`) and sometimes using a String field name (`"problemhistoryRef"`)? There is NO restriction on what you can and can't join to as long as it is a RELATION field.

Comment: we can use both scenarios to get reference join

Comment: Yes, but it is weird to mix both approaches in one query. Fact remains that there is no restriction in the JPA API for joining, so if your JPA provider throws an exception then you should report a bug on it

Comment: Join<ProblemReport,ProblemHistory> pblmReportHistoryJoin=root.join("prbHistory",JoinType.LEFT);

Comment: Is there any way if I make change in the above line